# ZF Error ZF tool setup

Tags: zend-framework, command-line-interface

Zend 1.9.1

so I get this error

> Blockquote
>   ***************************** ZF ERROR ********************************
>   In order to run the zf command, you need to ensure that Zend Framework
>   is inside your include_path.  If you are running this without Zendframework in your include-path, you can alternatively set one of two enviroment variables to for this tool to work
>
> ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH="/path/to/ZendFramework\library" or alternatively
>    ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH_PREPEND="/path/to/ZendFramework\library"
>
> attempted include_path: c:\php\includes;.
>
> script location: c:\php\bin\zf.php

looking at the attempted include path it shows that my include path is set to 'c:\php\includes', done so via php.ini

inside include folder is 'library/' folder which contains 'zend/'

and my zend bin folder is at c:php/bin

yet I still get this error when trying to use zf in command line?

Ive had a look at other questions to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Zend Framework 1 final release - version 1.12.11 to get around this headache and it worked perfectlt as it should have. Had to be a bug in the 1.9 version!